# Вернуться к /election/1

Tags: дефект, выборы

При просмотре [ревизий выборов](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/474441/revisions) в заголовке написано

> Вернуться к /election/1

и ссылка ведёт на

```
https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election/1
```

И текст, и ссылка неправильные. Должно быть `4`, а не `1`.

Comment: А номинально откуда выйти на эту страницу с ревизиями?

Comment: @αλεχολυτ, ну у меня кнопка есть: https://i.stack.imgur.com/um6GT.png